# mix up the values of Java linked List issue

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, for-loop, linked-list

i'm trying to mix up the values of my linked list using `Collections.shuffle` but i always get the same order every time this is the code who supposed to display and mix up my list of Card :

```
public Deck(int nbBox) {
    this.cardList = new LinkedList<Card>();
    Collections.shuffle(cardList);
    for (int i = 0; i < nbBox; i++) {
      for (Color col : Color.values()) {
        for (Value val : Value.values()) {
          cardList.add(new Card(val, col));
        }
      }

    }

  }
```

Comment: You shuffle before adding them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.cardList = new LinkedList<Card>();
    Collections.shuffle(cardList);
```

you were shuffling an empty list.

try to move the `shuffle()` line to the end of your method.

Answer (score 1):

you should first implement your cardList before being able to shuffle it

```
public Deck(int nbBox) {
    this.cardList = new LinkedList<Card>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nbBox; i++) {
      for (Color col : Color.values()) {
        for (Value val : Value.values()) {
          cardList.add(new Card(val, col));
        }
      }   
    }
  Collections.shuffle(cardList);     
}
```